# dynamically deleteing cardviews but error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have this code so far when the user presses the fab a cardview is added to the recyclerview. I also now made it so whenthe user presses a specific cardview, a dialog shows and when the user presses ok, that cardview gets deleted. but I have a problem

When there are 2 cardviews left in the recyclerview and i click to delete one of them I get this error:

```
10-01 09:20:45.473 28725-28725/com.app.supermarketaislefinder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:399)
        at com.app.supermarketaislefinder.ProductAdapter$2$2.onClick(ProductAdapter.java:123)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 123 is at this line
 `productList.remove(position);`

What can I do about that?

**ProductAdapter.java**

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

    private Map<Integer, Integer> mSpinnerSelectedItem = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();


//this context we will use to inflate the layout
    //Remove this..Please
    // CheckBox checkBox;

    //private Context mCtx;
    private SearchableSpinner spinner;

    //we are storing all the products in a list
    private List<Product> productList;

    private Activity create;

    public ProductAdapter(Activity activity) {
        create = activity;
    }


    //getting the context and product list with constructor
    public ProductAdapter(Activity activity, List<Product> productList) {
        // this.mCtx = mCtx;
        create = activity;
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //inflating and returning our view holder
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(create);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_products, null);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // //getting the product of the specified position


        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(create, R.layout.item_spinner_layout,
                Product.getSpinnerItemsList());
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        holder.spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int mPosition, long id) {
                mSpinnerSelectedItem.put(position, mPosition);

                TextView mTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.mSpinnerText);
           /* Toast.makeText(create, "Selected Item: " + mTextView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("***************", "Selected Item: " + mTextView.getText().toString());*/


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


        //binding the data with the viewholder views
        if (mSpinnerSelectedItem.containsKey(position)) {
            holder.spinner.setSelection(mSpinnerSelectedItem.get(position));
        }


        holder.getView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(create);


                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete Item");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity


                                holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
                                holder.spinner.setSelection(0);

                                productList.remove(position);
                                notifyItemRemoved(position);

                                Toast.makeText(create, "Item removed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, just close
                                // the dialog box and do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });





    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }


    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        SearchableSpinner spinner;
        EditText editText;
        TextView textView5;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        View rootView;


        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            spinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            editText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            textView5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            rootView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);


            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // makes the set disappear when checkbox is ticked.
                    if(isChecked){

                        checkBox.setChecked(false);
                        spinner.setSelection(0);

                        productList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                        notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());



                        Toast.makeText(create, "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            });



        }

        public View getView() {
            return rootView;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of an item inside your list may change while you add and remove items from it. So, the position you assigned in your `onClickListener` may not be the right one in the moment of the click.

Try with this:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    // ...

    productList.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());

    // ...
}
```

This way, you will be checking the position at the time of the click, not when you bind the `ViewHolder`.

Comment: Ah thanks. I am pretty sure I may have used or seen getAdapterPosition somewhere so yep. anyways thank you, I appreciate it!